# undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the following [Rails tutorial][1]

[1]: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-a_users_resource to learn and have gotten to the section I've linked to.

When I visit the REST URL xxx/users/1, I am getting the error:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#index
undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass
```

From reading online, I think it has to do with the code in the users model, but I've followed the tut to a tee, and my code seems to be the same as the original. But maybe someone else can see something I'm missing:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

Any help would be appreaciated!

Edit: here is the Framework trace from the error:

```
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:36:in `visible_action?'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:18:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:14:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:61:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:115:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4595614879947811243__call__2349863385936106112__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Edit again: Here is the users_controller.rb contents. Seems that may be the issue, but it's as listed in the tutorial:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = user.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

Comment: is there a stacktrace with the error message ?

Comment: check if you defined 'resources :users' in routes.rb and that you have the actions index, show, ... declared in controller

Comment: can you show the controller code please?

Comment: imho the error is not caused because of the code you have, but the code you don't have. as @user1829889 suggested, add an index action to your controller

Comment: Thanks everyone.

Just to let you know restarting the Rails server fixed the trick!

Comment: It would be good if this question was marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the Rails Server fixed the problem! Thanks